# Preventing nested callbacks in JavaScript that uses iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, promise, cheerio

Currently I'm using promises to try to prevent the need for nested callbacks in my code, but I've hit a setback. In this case, I'm using node's request-promise and cheerio to emulate jQuery on the server. However, at some point I need to call `jQuery.each()`, to create a request for each `<a>` element. Is there any way I can use promises to prevent this nested callback?

```
request("http://url.com").then(function (html) { 
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var rows = $("tr.class a");
    rows.each(function (index, el) {

        //Iterate over all <a> elements, and send a request for each one.
        //Can this code be modified to return a promise?
        //Is there another way to prevent this from being nested?

        request($(el).attr("href")).then(function (html) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var url = $("td>img").attr("src");
            return request(url);
        })
        .then(function (img) {
            //Save the image to the database
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I got in the end. Some incidental changes I made include using url.resolve to allow relative URLs to work.

```
var $ = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request-promise');
var url = require('url');

var baseURL = "http://url.com";

request(baseURL).then(function (html) {
    $("tr.class a", html).toArray(); 
}).map(function (el) {
    return request(url.resolve(baseURL, jq.attr("href")));
}).map(function (html) {
    var src = $("td>img", html).attr("src");
    return request(url.resolve(baseURL, src));
}).map(function (img) {
    //Save the image to the database
});
```

Thanks to Benjamin Gruenbaum for alterting me to the .map() method in bluebird.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Bluebird promises (code in other libraries is similar):

```
Promise.resolve(request("http://url.com").then(function (html) { 
    var $ = cheerio.load(html)("tr.class a");
})).map(function(el){ // map is `then` over an array
    return el.href;
}).map(request).map(function(html){
    return cheerio.load(html)("td>img").src;
}).map(request).map(function(img){
    // save to database.
});
```

Alternatively, you can define actions for a single link and then process those. It would look similar.

Comment: @SLaks wait, never mind - yes I do. While they use Bluebird - they don't expose its methods to the outside (god knows why) so resolve _is_ required.

Comment: Then what exactly does it return? Also, you're missing a `)`.

Comment: @SLaks About the `)` - I'm just closing it after the `then`. What `Promise.resolve` does is take a `then`able and convert it into a trusted Bluebird promise that exposes the whole API. What `request-promised` does is strip all the methods except then/catch/finally off the returned promise (it only exposes those).

Comment: I get the error `Possibly unhandled TypeError: expecting an array, a promise or a thenable`, but I'm not sure how this is supposed to work anyway. Is the .map() from bluebird? But doesn't that need an array of promises? And you're not returning anything from the first `.then()` anyway, so how would this work?